# IndexOutOfBoundsException while working with sessions

Tags: java, jsp, session, arraylist

I'm working with session in a web application, problem is when I store a value in a session, using another session to store a "max" index to keep track of the number of elements saved in the ArrayList.

```java
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

int a   =   (int) request.getSession().getAttribute("max");

System.out.print(a); // here a = 0 the first time 

list.add(request.getParameter("articolo")); // add a String value which in this case is a name of a product in my webapp

System.out.print((String) list.get(a)); // the just stored value gets printed

request.getSession().setAttribute("carrello" + a, list.get(a)); // add the just stored value in a session which is "carrello 0 " in this case

request.getSession().setAttribute("max", a+1);// increment the max index in session max

//list.clear();  i've also tried to do this to prevent the error 

request.getSession().setAttribute("messaggio","Prodotto aggiunto al carrello!");   // just a message saying " Product added to cart "

response.sendRedirect("visualizzaTab.jsp");  // redirect to a jsp page
```

I'm getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException, I assure you that max session value is set to 0 after i print every product stored in the "cart" session. If you need more code just comment below

Answer (score 0):

Your list will always be empty because of the following line:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

However, because you modified the "max" session attribute to be 1 in the following line:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("max", a+1);// increment the max index in session max
```

The IndexOutOfBoundsException will occur when any subsequent request hits the following line of code because the list is empty:

```
System.out.print((String) list.get(a)); // the just stored value gets printed
```